# Pandas df calculate cost per day

Tags: python, pandas

I have a df like this:

```
USD       | Time 
15600.20  | 300 days
50000.25  | 150 days
```

I have converted some numbers to days as the table above, however when trying to do a Time / USD it gives me a value in time, what would be the best way to get:

```
USD       | Time     | Cost/day
15600.20  | 300 days |   50
50000.25  | 150 days | 333.33
```

Comment: df.USD.div(df.Time.dt.days)

Answer (score 0):

How about:

`df['Cost/Day'] = df['USD']/df['Time'].apply(lambda x: float(x.strip()[:-4]))`